# show name as well as ID from two different tables for one Model in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables here both with their respective scaffold generated controllers and models:

```
services
id|service_type|details

service_type
id|service_type
```

Service_type table just holds a list of service types such as:

```
1. CLeaning
2. Grouting
3. Polishing
```

Services refers to different instances of each type of service - so a service order made for polishing would have 3 as the service_type.

When I list down the list of services I want to show the corresponding service_type.service_type entry for services.service_type where services.service_type = service_type.id

Is it possible to set up the services model to do this in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Ali, How are the two tables different? Can you describe a bit more? You have not described the relation between the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be modeled in rails. You need to add following relationships in your models

In `service_type` model add

```
has_many : services
```

In `service` model add

```
 belongs_to : service_type
```

Then you need to add another field to your 'service'  model called 'service_type_id' which rails will use as a foreign key.

also you will have to rename 'service_type' field from the services table because it will conflict with rails naming convention.

Now you are set.

```
service_type.services
```

will now give you all orders of that particular service type

service.service_type will give you the row from service_type model